# Python script to skip specific column in CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a Python code which filters the data according to specific column and creates multiple CSV files.

Here is my main csv file:

```
Name,    City,      Email
john     cty_1      a@g.com
jack     cty_1      b@g.com
...
Ross     cty_2      c@g.com
Rachel   cty_2      d@g.com
...
```

My python logic currently creates separate csv for separate city. Existing python logic is:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('filtered_final.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) #skip header
    
    #Group by column (city)
    lst = sorted(reader, key=lambda x : x[1])
    groups = groupby(lst, key=lambda x : x[1])

    #Write file for each city
    for k,g in groups:
        filename = k[21:] + '.csv'
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as fout:
            csv_output = csv.writer(fout)

            csv_output.writerow(["Name","City","Email"])  #header
            for line in g:
                csv_output.writerow(line)
```

Now, I want to remove the "City" Column on each new CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data is small enough to put on ram, you can just read the whole thing in and do a groupby:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filtered_final.csv')

for city, data in df[['Name','Email']].groupby(df['City']):
    data.to_csv(f'{city}_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi Quang, Here you have used 'pd'. Is it a library? Do we need to import that one?

Comment: @DeependraDangal it's standard shorthand for `pandas`, which you tagged.

Comment: Okay @Quang . It worked. But in the new CSV files, one additional identifier is automatically added in the first column(before Name and Email column)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to pass `index=False` into `to_csv`. See updates.

Answer (score 1):

Then try to import like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filtered_final.csv', usecols=['Name','Email'])
```